# How to add dynamic overlays (eg. scorecard) to live stream (eg. youtube) using swift

Tags: ios, swift, overlay, live-streaming, watermark

Using `LFLiveKit` I can stream to `youtube`, it supports watermark view but it is static that I can't add webview as overlay.

The watermark view is added to full video size only in `480*640` pixel resolution. When pixel resolution is increased the watermark view shrinks.

```
session.warterMarkView = overlayview
```

I need to know how to add webview which is like scorecard to live stream with full video size.